# Displaying different attributes within layer with individual colors in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, data, layers, color, display

I am trying to display different soil types within a geological soil layer with individual colors per each type of soil. As of now it is displaying all as the same color.

[image]

Comment: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You can take care of this in Layer Styling in QGIS 3. In the layer contents, click the Layer Styling icon.

[image: Layer Styling]

When the syling interface opens, change the type from Single Symbol to Categorized. Then define a Column to symbolize on.

[image: Categorized]

[image]

At this point, your map is probably still blank. Go ahead and choose a Color Ramp, click the Classify button in the bottom left, then Apply (if Live update is unchecked). At this point, your table of contents of layers will be updated as well.

[image: Apply Settings]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

To build off JGH comments.

You could use this tutorial as reference - [Basic Vector Styling](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html), it covers

> To create a map, one has to style the GIS data and present it in a form that is visually informative. There are a large number of options available in QGIS to apply different types of symbology to the underlying data. In this tutorial, we will explore some basics of styling.

I've included a couple of screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! Got it figured out now!